# how to read json response in jsp

Tags: java, json

My client side program is like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(req);
```

Server side, I have composed a JSON response.

```
JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject();
JObject.put("ResponseCode", "100");
JObject.put("Status", "Success");
response.setContentType("application/json");    
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(JObject);
out.flush();
```

How can i read this `ResponseCode` and `Status` in Client side back.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the JSOn string to an object. If using Javascript you can use `JSON.parse(json_str)` or `$.parseJSON` if you use jQuery. After you have done it you can access those entries as usual:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json_str);
var code = obj["ResponseCode"];
```

#### Edit

Using Java:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json_string);
String code = obj.getString("ResponseCode");
```

Comment: Salem, thanks for the quick response.. My client side program is in java. tried below: JSONObject jsonDataObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(res.toString()); String ResponseCode = ((String)jsonDataObject.get("ResponseCode")); And received java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpResponse res = client.execute(req);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";
line = rd.readLine();  /// Json Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
StatusLine statusLine = res.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == 200) // or whatever 
                {
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "utf-8"));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    builder.append(line);
}

sRet = builder.toString();

...

tknr = new JSONTokener(sRet);
```