# ajax call from php to a jsp page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a php link given to me i could use to get an output:

{foo:"fooName",fooLast:"fooLastName"}

i wish to use this output in a jsp file through ajax

my script looks like this

```
    function loadEmpName(empId){
                var urlpath = "http://mysite.com:8080/searchByUid?"+empId;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlpath,
                    dataType: "html",
                    contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(result) {
//success here (most probably output to a <div> the result

                    },
                    error: function(error){
                        //errors here
                    }
                });
           }
```

im not getting any error but im not getting the desired output. Is this even possible to begin with?

I read about not being able to do a cross domain ajax call, im wondering if this is the case

Comment: `"http://mysite.com:8080/searchByUid?"+empId;`. Is there intentionally no file extension here?

Comment: i think so , its returning a string

Answer (score 1):

Have you confused JSP with JavaScript? Just pointing out.
You can simply do this using JavaScript like so:

```
var strJSON = '{foo:"fooName",fooLast:"fooLastName"}';
var objJSON = eval("(function(){return " + strJSON + ";})()");
alert(objJSON.foo);
alert(objJSON.fooLast);
```

For JSP check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481295/how-to-read-json-response-in-jsp).

Comment: i am not sure what you suggest here, i am trying to output a string from a php link to a jsp page i have by using ajax to put the response of that php on a part of my jsp page.